# dropdown menu jquery with add and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, slide

So i'm trying to make a jquery dropdown that adds and removes classes. It does work, but only once. If i try the dropdown again, it simply drops down and slides up right after. It's suppose to drop down after clicking a button and slide up after another click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //dropdown menu function
        $(".menuDrop").click(function(){
            $(".nav").slideDown("slow");
            $(".menuDrop").addClass("btn-hover");
            $(".menuDrop").click(function(){
                $(".nav").slideUp("slow");
                $(".menuDrop").removeClass("btn-hover");
            });
        });
    });
```

The "btn-hover" class is meant to add the same css as it where in a hover state once the button is clicked.

--edit--

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="button" class="menuDrop btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a class="link" href="#">home</a></li>
            <hr>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that this goes with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using slideToggle and toggleClass should help you achieve this, and with less code:

```
//dropdown menu function
$(".menuDrop").click(function(){
    $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".menuDrop").toggleClass("btn-hover");
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scesR/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, didn't think of toggleClass. Thanks! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind it using **`change`** event, instead of *`click`* event.

```
$(".menuDrop").change(function(){
            $(".nav").slideDown("slow");
            $(".menuDrop").addClass("btn-hover");
            $(".menuDrop").click(function(){
                $(".nav").slideUp("slow");
                $(".menuDrop").removeClass("btn-hover");
            });
        });
```